# Embed tweet into Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I embed a tweet into Twitter Bootstrap? Twitter embed uses  which Twitter Bootstrap overrides and loses all the Twitter UI and functionality. What is the way around this so that Twitter embeds show in Bootstrap? Thanks in advance for the help!

Here's an example: http://www.bootply.com/3k4WKA1cLU In the preview you see that the embedded tweet should look like. Now run it and you'll see all the Twitter UI and functionality is stripped and it's just a blockquote.

Comment: You ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap adds border-left,margin and padding properties for the blockquote element.so you can override it by this following code.

```
/* Override the bootstrap style */
blockquote {
    border-left: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

for all twit embed give a class i.e i gave twitter-tweet as the class naem then for following code gives required css ...

```
blockquote.twitter-tweet {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, "Segoe UI", Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-color: #eee #ddd #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;
  max-width: 468px;
}

blockquote.twitter-tweet p {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 20px;
}

 blockquote.twitter-tweet a {
   color: inherit;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
   outline: 0 none;
 }

 blockquote.twitter-tweet a:hover,
 blockquote.twitter-tweet a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer to prevent deletion (code-only answers are likely to get deleted, since they don't explain the solution).

Comment: Unfortunately this just removes the blockquote border and does not add back in the Twitter functionality.